# @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True) not doing anything

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am writing a discord bot for my server and I want a timeout commands that works only for people that have the admin perm, but when i switch to my alt account in the server that *dosent* have that perm, it still lets me timeout people. Why??

This is the code I have right now:

```
@bot.tree.command(name = 'timeout', description = 'time out a member')
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def timeout(interaction: discord.Interaction, member: discord.Member, seconds: int = 0, minutes: int = 0, hours: int = 0, days: int = 0, rule_violation_num: int = 0):
  embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Timedout...', description = f'{member.mention} was timedout for violating rule number {rule_violation_num}')
  embed.add_field(name = 'Responsible Mod:', value = interaction.user.mention)
  embed.set_author(name = interaction.user.name, icon_url = interaction.user.avatar.url)
  embed.set_thumbnail(url = member.display_avatar)
  embed.set_footer(text = time, icon_url = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1118276267695931544/1120369092537352214/Alloa_Academy_Badge.jpg')
  duration = datetime.timedelta(seconds = seconds, minutes = minutes, hours = hours, days = days)

  await member.timeout(duration)
  await interaction.response.send_message(embed = embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because you are working with an interaction/ slash command. You might have to use an if statement with app_commands

```py
@bot.tree.command(…)
@app_commands.checks.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def timeout()
```

Also: if you struggle with something, consider to read the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=app_commands#discord.app_commands.checks.has_permissions)

Comment: nevermind none of that works 

Comment: What exactly did not work? Was it the ignoring again?

Comment: app_commands is apparently not defined

Comment: oh then import it from the discord lib

Comment: from discord import app_commands

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much @Karo you dont know how long ive been trying to do this, thank you so much!

Comment: if youre problem is solved, make sure to accept the answer so its marked as correctly answered